# Linked List not accepting values

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, printf

I need to make a calendar planner with a linked list in C. Im inserting a couple of Elements, and I want to insert them in a sorted order. If I try to print the List, It doesn't show any output for the description of the appointment.

Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// Appointment
typedef struct
{
    time_t start;
    char *description;
} Appointment;

// List element
typedef struct Element
{
    Appointment *appointment;
    struct Element *next;
} Element;

// List of appointments
typedef struct
{
    Element *head, *tail;
} List;

void printAppointment(Appointment *appointment)
{
/*
    Print the Appointment structure
*/

    char *description = appointment->description;
    time_t startTime = appointment->start;
    printf("Appointment(%s, %ld)\n", description, startTime);
}

Appointment createAppointment(char *description, time_t start)
{
    Appointment appointment = {0};
    appointment.description = description;
    appointment.start = start;

    return appointment;
}

List createList()
/*
    Create a linked list with a head and a tail element
*/
{
    Element *head;
    Element *tail;

    head = malloc(sizeof(Element));
    tail = malloc(sizeof(Element));

    head->next = tail;

    List *list;

    list = malloc(sizeof(List));
    list->head = head;
    list->tail = tail;

    return *list;
}

void clearList(List list)
/*
    Free the list from all memory allocated, but keep the head and the tail
*/
{
    Element *temp;

    // Free elements as long as the head is not pointing to the tail
    while (list.head->next != list.tail)
    {
        // Extract the element after the head into temp, point head at the element after
        temp = list.head->next;
        list.head->next = temp->next;

        // Free the exctracted element
        free(temp);
    }
}

void debugList(List list)
/*
    Print the list to the console
*/
{

    struct Element *current = list.head->next;
    while (current->appointment != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s ", current->appointment->description);
        
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void insertElement(List list, char *description, time_t start)
/*
    Insert a new element into the list based on its value
*/
{

    printf("Inserting element %s with start time %ld\n", description, start);
    Element *new_element = malloc(sizeof(struct Element));
    Appointment new_appointment = createAppointment(description, start);
    
    new_element->appointment = &new_appointment;
    new_element->next = NULL;

    if (list.head->next == list.tail)
    {
        // List is empty, insert new element after the head
        printf("Head is pointing to tail, inserting %s in the middle\n", description);
     
        new_element->next = list.tail;
        list.head->next = new_element;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // Find the correct position for the new node in the list
        struct Element *current = list.head->next;
        struct Element *prev = list.head;

        int index = 0;

        while (1)
        {
            // If the new value is bigger than the current value, insert it before the current element
            if (current->appointment->start >= start)
            {
                printf("Inserting element %s at position %d\n", description, index);
                prev->next = new_element;
                new_element->next = current;
                return;
            }

            // Iterate forwards
            prev = current;
            current = current->next;
            index++;

            // If the new element is bigger than all elements, insert it at the end
            if (current == list.tail)
            {
                prev->next = new_element;
                new_element->next = list.tail;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

Element *findElement(List list, char *description)
{
    /*
        Find a element in the list based on its value. Returns nullptr if the element is not found.
    */
    Element *current = list.head->next;
    while (current->next != list.tail)
    {
        Appointment currentAppointment = *current->appointment;
        
        printf("Appointment(%s, %ld)\n", currentAppointment.description, currentAppointment.start);
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("Returning NULL, no element found!");
    return NULL;
}

_Bool deleteElement(List list, char *description)
{
    /*
        Find a element in the list based on its value and delete it. Returns true if the element has been deleted.
    */
    Element *current = list.head->next;
    Element *prev = list.head;

    while (current->next != list.tail)
    {
        char *currentDescription = current->appointment->description;

        if (*currentDescription == *description)
        {
            prev->next = current->next;
            free(current);
            return true;
        }
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    // Create the list
    List list = createList();

    // Insert some nodes
    insertElement(list, "test1", time(NULL) - 1000);
    insertElement(list, "test3", time(NULL) - 3000);
    insertElement(list, "test2", time(NULL) - 2000);
    insertElement(list, "test4", time(NULL) - 4000);
    insertElement(list, "test8", time(NULL) - 8000);

    // Print the list
    debugList(list);


    return 0;

    // Search the element with value 3
    Element *el = malloc(sizeof(Element)); 
    el = findElement(list, "test3");

    //printAppointment(el->appointment);
    //printAppointment(el->next->appointment);

    // Delete the element with value 3
    deleteElement(list, "test3");
    debugList(list);

    // clear the list
    clearList(list);

    // print the list again;
    debugList(list);
    return 0;
}
```

I can't change any of the structs since those are a given requirement. Im fairly new to C so I dont really know why this is happening and I have absolutely no Idea on how to fix this.

The program has been compiled with `gcc -g -Wall -pedantic-errors main.c`

Comment: You are using `Appointment` pointer to indicate that you reached the end of the list. But you do not initialized your `head` and `tail` nodes. That could cause undefined behaviour if you run behind the end of your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a pointer to a list when you insert elements. Right now you're passing a copy, to which you add an element, but this is not applied to your variable but to a copy of your variable. Change your function signature to:

```
void insertElement(List* list, char *description, time_t start)
```

and change all code inside the function accordingly to deal with a pointer instead of a value. Your main will look like this:

```
int main()
{
    // Create the list
    List list = createList();

    // Insert some nodes
    insertElement(&list, "test1", time(NULL) - 1000);
    insertElement(&list, "test3", time(NULL) - 3000);
    insertElement(&list, "test2", time(NULL) - 2000);
    insertElement(&list, "test4", time(NULL) - 4000);
    insertElement(&list, "test8", time(NULL) - 8000);

    // Print the list
    debugList(list);


    return 0;
}
```

and the `insertElement` function:

```
void insertElement(List* list, char *description, time_t start)
/*
    Insert a new element into the list based on its value
*/
{

    printf("Inserting element %s with start time %ld\n", description, start);
    Element *new_element = malloc(sizeof(struct Element));
    Appointment new_appointment = createAppointment(description, start);
    
    new_element->appointment = &new_appointment;
    new_element->next = NULL;

    if (list->head->next == list->tail)
    {
        // List is empty, insert new element after the head
        printf("Head is pointing to tail, inserting %s in the middle\n", description);
     
        new_element->next = list->tail;
        list->head->next = new_element;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // Find the correct position for the new node in the list
        struct Element *current = list->head->next;
        struct Element *prev = list->head;

        int index = 0;

        while (1)
        {
            // If the new value is bigger than the current value, insert it before the current element
            if (current->appointment->start >= start)
            {
                printf("Inserting element %s at position %d\n", description, index);
                prev->next = new_element;
                new_element->next = current;
                return;
            }

            // Iterate forwards
            prev = current;
            current = current->next;
            index++;

            // If the new element is bigger than all elements, insert it at the end
            if (current == list->tail)
            {
                prev->next = new_element;
                new_element->next = list->tail;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**PS** There are more functions in your code where you should pass a pointer to a list instead of a copy.

**Not recommended but for completion:**

Another solution is to return your list everytime you insert an element, but this will be slower and you have to reassign your list everytime you insert a new element, so NOT recommended but here is the function signature anyway:

```
List insertElement(List list, char *description, time_t start)
```

Comment: Thank you, trying it out real quick. The whole thing with pointers and references is still extremly new to me...

Comment: While this is generally correct, it is not related to the problem in the question. The `list` itself is not modified in the function but only the head and tail nodes linked from `list`.

Comment: @Gerhardh the list is modified though, isnt it? If head and tail are struct members, and you edit them through your list pointer, meaning the list itself is edited

Comment: Correct, but where are they modified? Modifying `list.head->next` is different thing.